# What does "developed in discernment" mean?

Tags: personal-practice, reference-request, pali-canon

From the [Lonaphala Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html):

> Now, a trifling evil act done by what sort of individual is
>   experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears
>   for a moment? There is the case where a certain individual is
>   **developed in the body, developed in virtue, developed in mind [i.e.,
>   painful feelings cannot invade the mind and stay there], developed in
>   discernment: unrestricted, large-hearted, dwelling with the
>   immeasurable**. A trifling evil act done by this sort of individual is
>   experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears
>   for a moment.

What developed in body and developed in mind means, is elaborated in [MN36](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.036.than.html):

> "And how is one developed in body and developed in mind? There is the
>   case where a pleasant feeling arises in a well-educated disciple of
>   the noble ones. On being touched by the pleasant feeling, he doesn't
>   become impassioned with pleasure, and is not reduced to being
>   impassioned with pleasure. His pleasant feeling ceases. With the
>   cessation of the pleasant feeling there arises a painful feeling. On
>   being touched with the painful feeling, he doesn't sorrow, grieve, or
>   lament, beat his breast or becomes distraught. When that pleasant
>   feeling had arisen in him, it didn't invade his mind and remain
>   because of his development of the body. When that painful feeling had
>   arisen in him, it didn't invade his mind and remain because of his
>   development of the mind. This is how one is developed in body and
>   developed in mind."

What being developed in [virtue (sila)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/index.html) means, is covered by the [Five Precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/pancasila.html) (and also the [Eight Precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/atthasila.html) and [Ten Precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/dasasila.html)), [Right Speech](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-vaca/index.html), [Right Action](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-kammanto/index.html) and [Right Livelihood](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ajivo/index.html). These links provide more info on these.

However, what does "developed in discernment" mean?

Please also provide references from the scriptures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word translated "developed in discernment" is *bhāvitapañño*, i.e. increased or developed *pañña*.

The dictionary entry for [*pañña*](https://suttacentral.net/define/pa%C3%B1%C3%B1a) says,

> of wisdom, endowed with knowledge or insight, possessed of the highest cognition

The dictionary definition lists a lot of places where it's used in various compounds, (possibly describing various types of wisdom or insight) -- including the *bhāvita* compound, which is used in for example [SN 35.127](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.127/en/sujato) (in summary, immune to sexual desire, and guarding the senses) and [AN 10.24](https://suttacentral.net/an10.24/en/sujato) (in summary, immune to various [unwholesome mental factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_factors_(Buddhism)#Fourteen_unwholesome_mental_factors)).

I'd say these describe the effect of wisdom rather than describing the object of wisdom -- but, that's not surprising because what it's describing is "developed wisdom" i.e. the effect of having perfected wisdom.

I guess you'd have to look at other places *pañña* is used by itself (to find a description of *pañña* itself), and/or other *pañña* compounds (for descriptions of the various types of *pañña*).<sup>1</sup>

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praj%C3%B1%C4%81_(Buddhism)) says it means "insight into the three characteristics": quoting Gombrich and others.

It's one of the several [perfections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81ramit%C4%81) (i.e. virtues which can be "perfected" or [completed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar))).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Not easy to summarise:</sub>

- A [search of SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=pa%C3%B1%C3%B1a) returns 500 results -- many from the Abhidamma and so on.
- [AN 8.2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.002.than.html) describes 8 different types of discernment (which may confirm my theory that there are many different types or aspects of wisdom, that's it's not a term with a narrow meaning)
- *Pañña* is an entire branch of the [Threefold Training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_Training), so I expect it includes right view and right intention

Answer (score 0):

Developed in discernment (wisdom) means developed in Noble Right View rather than attached and burdened by the ignoble right view of reincarnation, as explained in [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html).

It follows a trifling evil act done by this sort of individual is experienced in the here & now and, for the most part, barely appears for a moment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76883/discussion-on-answer-by-dhammadhatu-what-does-developed-in-discernment-mean).