# Is understanding a "bring-debt" or "gain-debt"?

Tags: abhidhamma, right-view, sila

Having read "...is an ethical duty to acquire knowledge in order to improve our understanding", my person thought to investigate the matter in frame of the Dhamma. Against this sentence stands the common public idea and advertising of "knowledge, info, is a common right".

What does the Buddha say, right view accounts, in relation whether understanding is a "bring-duty, debt" ([Bringschuld](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bringschuld), [Jura] *debt to be discharged at creditor's domicile, duty to inform the colleagues*)  or a "gain duty, debt" ([Holschuld](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holschuld), [JURA] *debt to be discharged at the domicile of the debtor /obligation to be performed at the place of business of the debtor*)?

Does one with right view think "I have/would have a right for knowledge and understanding" or "I have/would have to make sacrifices to gain knowledge and understanding?

Of course one can use google to help investigating.

*[Of course not at all given for trade and exchange, but as means for liberation from this corrupt wheel]*

Comment: Please provide some support (evidence, reference, quote) for this generalizing assertion:  "stands the common public idea and advertising of "knowledge, info, is a common right"" - where does this idea stand? Is it really common?

Comment: I guess it's crossed wires -- [in context](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/34706/254), Peter might have been saying "we have a duty to understand" in order to avoid being harmful -- whereas the OP's idea when posting that topic was maybe about, something like, its being blameworthy to post answers which are merely well-intentioned but ignorant.

Comment: This means knowning the things that relate to the issues people are facing to get along.

Comment: If not knowing that "one gains what one gives" yes, householder @Yvain . Beings are not aware of their dependency, not aware of goodness and foolishness is the cause of suffering, may one be pride as one likes. Giving downward tends downwardly.

Comment: @Samana Johann your answer is really innapropriate. Not to say wrong. You call me a housekeeper and you just don't know. I have no time for this go and seek the ones you lost back in the days, i'm too far away from your misconceptions.

Comment: Householder are busy,  householder @Yvain . No problem and however he likes to perceive things. Else is a "gain-duty".

Comment: i'm on 'health program' that means take in babylon drugs that are raping my mind, if I don't do so they take me away and put me in a cell where they make a game of my games. My mother calls me a monster, I have cancerous and leucemic attacks by attack I mean that it goes back and forth and that I allways beat it untill now. My father treats me like a little girl despite of this and what I see is only justice and love forever, I'm not a housekeeper. Bless you.

Comment: There is no better medicine then goodwill, forgiveness and [the healing power of precepts](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/precepts_en.html), householder @Yvain . Feel always welcome [here](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=forum) if possible to leave.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it seems like a *Bringschuld* -- e.g. the "debt" (of gratitude) which you owe to your parents is apparently to be repaid "to" your parents (so, by analogy, "at the creditor's domicile").

I think that when the Buddha taught, it was out of compassion -- and the way to "repay" that was by practising properly and benefiting -- so for example the Buddha requested or advised (in [MN 103](https://suttacentral.net/mn103/en/sujato)) that the monks should not quarrel amongst themselves. Perhaps you'd call that a *Holschuld*, i.e. an action performed by the monks in their own place and time.

Finally, assuming that Rahula gained understanding as a result of "reflecting" on his actions as described in [MN 61](https://suttacentral.net/mn61/en/sujato) -- I'm not sure I see any "debt", at all, associated with that.

Comment: The Buddha and his generations of noble disciples gave out of compassion would be a great and protective observation, indeed. No duty at all did they have.

Answer (score 1):

'Sacrifices' is puthujjana dharma, as follows:

> *And what is right view that is accompanied by defilements, has the attributes of good deeds, and ripens in attachment? ‘There is meaning
>   in giving, sacrifice, and offerings...' MN 117*
>
> *'Householders, if wife and husband want to see each other in both this life and the next, they should be equals in faith, ethical
>   conduct, sacrifice (caga) and
>   wisdom...' AN 4.55*

'Sacrifice' is, for example, what a husband does so he can win the sexual favour of his wife.

If we think we are 'sacrificing' something, this means we still value the object of sacrifice.

Where as the Path is from dispassion. When there is dispassion & disenchantment towards all of the world (as the Buddha taught), there is nothing of value to sacrifice.

For example, Abraham was prepared to sacrifice his son Issac to please his worldly God. Where as the Buddha left his son to attain Nibbana (freedom from the world).

Comment: I'm not sure that the *caga* in that context means giving to each other, i.e. trading among themselves for each other's sexual favour. I interpreted it as, a married couple or family being generous towards others in (and outside of) society. The "sacrifice" meaning of *caga* is more Hindu, isn't it, i.e. "offerings" to a God?

Answer (score 1):

"ethical duty to acquire knowledge in order to improve our understanding" means, if we stay stupid, we will create bad karma (trouble) for everyone , therefore we must learn, in order to understand what to do.

"Must learn" - there is no debt here.

"Must learn" - there is no common right.

If we don't learn, we will keep getting everyone in trouble.
That's what this means.

Comment: "Acquire" means "get", not "share".